# UITableView on top UIScrollView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I putting `UITableView` on top `UIScrollView`, and when I want to scroll the `UITableView`, it is not scrolling .... (the `UIScrollView` didScroll function isn't running).
I worked in the storyboard.
My code:

```
CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
  [_myScrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(screenSize.size.width, screenSize.size.height)];
   _myScrollView.delegate = self; 
     _tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _myScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

V. B. 
I wont the `UIScrollView` to scroll, not the `UITableView`...

Comment: can you add more code

Comment: I don't have more code, (except the standard UITableView code).

Answer (score 0):

Change the contentSize of your scrollView. It is set to screen size now. Use this code

```
[_myScrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(screenSize.size.width, 2 * screenSize.size.height)];
```

Comment: it's working, but when i'm scrolling down the table not reloading data, even that i'm calling the [_tableView.reloadData] in scrollView didScroll, and in scrollViewWillBeginDragging... (i can se only the first 12 rows).

Answer (score 0):

I tought you're hierarchy is like::

```
UIView
  - UIScrollView  (outerscroll)
       - Some other views and buttons
       - UITableView (tableView)
```

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you shouldn't embed a UITableViewinside a UIScrollView.

**Important:** You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.
Your problem is really related to what your UIScrollView does.

But if it's just to hide the tableview when needed (that was my case), you can just move the UITableView in its superview.

I found a small example here : https://github.com/rvirin/SoundCloud/